# angular js tutorial - clarification needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm working on my first MEAN application, using the following tutorial:
http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/09/28/angularjs-tutorial-for-beginners-with-nodejs-expressjs-and-mongodb/

Today is literally day 1 for me with Angular.js. I'm having a little difficulty following some of the code examples and I'm hoping someone here can fill in the blanks.

Specifically, on that page, there's an example under the heading: 
"AngularJS Routes (ngRoutes)".

**Question**
In the CodePen example, I'm not sure how to organize the files on my test box to run the demo.  He's got HTML separated from the JS.

In the HTML code, I see that it makes reference to "todo.html" .  Is that where I put the stuff that's currently under the "JS" tab in the codepen window?

Some clarification would be appreciated.  I'm also reviewing the quick start guide on the angular site to see if it's a little easier to follow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He indeed has the JS code and html code separated into different files. In practice you need to include a reference to your js file in the html, typically in within the document `<head></head>` like so:

```
<script src="yourJSFile.js"></script>
```

where "yourJSFile" is the name of your javascript file. 
In the codepen however, this doesn't have to be explicitly referenced since it's an app for prototyping that includes the js listed in the JS tab for you.

I think what your looking for would be to set up your project this way:

- projectFolder/todo.html <- contains your html code
- projectFolder/todo.js <- contains all your client side js code

Where "projectFolder" is the directory your project is in.